# Size of an image given the mm of a lens

Tags: optics, video

This comes from the world of video.  I'm shooting an event with 20-300mm zoom lenses on HD video cameras.  The cameras are physically 35 feet from the stage, given that information how tight of a shot (width x height) can I get given those numbers on a 6' person?

Answer (score 3):

You need focal length and also the size of the camera sensor, WxH in mm of sensor size. If the camera is 16:9 format in a 3:2 or 4:3 camera sensor, you need the 16:9 frame size at the sensor.

Then field of view calculators give you the field of view for a specified focus distance.
One is http://www.scantips.com/lights/fieldofview.html

Comment: Heh, beat me to the punch with the same link.

Comment: @SandorDosa the difference is, that link is published by Wayne, and not you. =)

Comment: @scottbb Yeah, that would tend to help...   Oh well.